# Handle Method not being called in Laravel Redis Queue

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

When adding an item to the queue, for some reason the handle method is not being called.

The Log entry in __construct is appearing but when attempting to log in handle(), nothing appears.

The method i'm using to dispatch is `ProcessImport::dispatch($path, $task->task_id);`

My queue service is configured to use Redis, and redis is storing all the data accordingly.

[image: Redis keys]

I am using Laravel 8. What could be wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Tasks;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Http\Controllers\Products\Products;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed;
use Throwable;
class ProcessImport implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $file_path;
    protected $response;
    protected $task;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($path, $task_id)
    {
        Log::info("Importing products (construct)");
        $this->task = Tasks::where('task_id', $task_id)->first();
        $this->file_path = $path;
        Log::info('Importing ' . $path);
    }

    private function getFilePath() {
        return $this->file_path;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->task->failed($exception->getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Get the cache driver for the unique job lock.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
     */
    public function uniqueVia()
    {
        return Cache::driver('redis');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("Importing products (handle)");
        $this->task->start();
        $products = new Products();
        $products->importProductsFromCSV($this->getFilePath());
        $this->task->success();
        Log::info("End of importing products..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: Is this a background process? How does it exactly work? I must've missed it in docs.

Comment: You can check here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#the-queue-work-command

Comment: Thanks @CuongLeNgoc - feel free to post answer and ill pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just pushed the jobs onto the queue but haven't started a worker to process them. You can run the worker with:

```
php artisan queue:work
```